# How to convert Arabic calendar to Gregorian calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to convert Islamic calendar to Gregorian calendar. You can see in this page [(Islamic calendar)](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) that once I press the convert button, it has to convert into Gregorian calendar and display it in another text box using jQuery.

I am also looking for an Islamic calendar and date picker. I didn't get one anywhere.

for example you can see this [website and select hijri tab and click convert](http://www.islamicity.org/hijri-gregorian-converter/#)

Answer (score 0):

i found this in google search and dont know why dont get answer after a year!!

you can use this function to convert hijri to georgian

```
function HijriToJD($m, $d, $y){
   return (int)((11 * $y + 3) / 30) + 354 * $y + 
     30 * $m - (int)(($m - 1) / 2) + $d + 1948440 - 385;
}


$date = HijriToJD(8, 4, 1439);//today

echo jdtogregorian($date);
```